# Getting parts of an xml file and bundle them up in a new one

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I'm trying to create a new xml file with parts from other xml files. For example i got these 2 xml files:

file 1:

```
<root> 
    <persons>
        <person1>
            <name> </name>
            <address> </address>
            <number> </number>
        </person1>
        <person2>
            <name> </name>
            <address> </address>
            <number> </number>
        </person2>
    </persons>
</root>
```

file 2:

```
<registration>
    <results>
        <result1>
            <test1> </test1>
            <Test2> </test2>
        </result1>
        <result2>
            <test1> </test1>
            <Test2> </test2>
        </result2>
    </results>
</registration>
```

The new xml file should look like this:

```
<combined>
    <persons> 
        <person1>
            <name> </name>
            <address> </address>
            <number> </number>
        </person1>
        <person2>
            <name> </name>
            <address> </address>
            <number> </number>
        </person2>
    </persons>
    <results>
        <result1>
            <test1> </test1>
            <Test2> </test2>
        </result1>
        <result2>
            <test1> </test1>
            <Test2> </test2>
        </result2>
    </results>
</combined>
```

How can I accomplish this in C# with `xmldocument`?

EDIT

Some more information, the nodes "persons" and "results" should be put in the new xml document (including "persons" and "results").

Comment: Any reason not to use XDocument or something else?

Comment: No particular reason. If you know who i could accomplish this with XDocument, thats fine with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XElement root1 = XElement.Load(file1);
XElement root2 = XElement.Load(file2);
XElement combined = new XElement("combined");

foreach(XElement node1 in root1.Elements())
    combined.Add(node1);

foreach(XElement node2 in root2.Elements())
    combined.Add(node2);

combined.Save(file3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically:

```
var doc1 = XElement.Load(file1);
var doc2 = XElement.Load(file2);

var combined = new XElement("combined", doc1.Descendants("person"), doc2);

combined.Save(file3);
```

Comment: Hi, I updated my question. Also, the document should be saved to disk. Should the var 'combined' be converted to something XDocument() understands?

Comment: Your sample data is not entirely consistent but it should be easy to work out the exact selection from doc1 and doc2.

Comment: It should now be consistent. I was making a quick example on this site. I just edit everything in notepad++.